# Get style attributes programmatically from kmlplacemark

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I am parsing the KML loaded on Google Map like:

```
Iterable<KmlPlacemark> placemarks = kmlLayer.getContainers().iterator().next().getPlacemarks();

for (KmlPlacemark placemark:placemarks){
//// HERE I WANT TO GET <style> VALUES OF placemark///////
}
```

I am getting placemarks fine, but how can I get the attributes of  tag under placemark? For example color of the placemark.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution:

```
    int lineColor = placemark.getInlineStyle().getPolylineOptions().getColor();
        if (lineColor == 0xffc0c0c0) {
// Do your stuff
        }
```